# How google's Map SDK billing works for Android and iOS apps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google Maps SDk for iOS and Android in my apps. Below are my use cases:

1. Load Map in both iOS and Android mobile Apps.
2. Draw few markers of locations received from my server.

I am not using any other Google Maps API.

Will I be billed for the above use cases?

I have tried reading Google's official billing documentation but could not understand the same.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/?_ga=2.43009189.1087723775.1573015191-1574282968.1573015191

Comment: classic Googlers - their documentation is almost always incomplete, ambiguous, or not very clear. 80% times I use any of their APIs, I have to look on internet or stackoverflow for additional answers...It should not be like that imho, and I had never had the same problem with other frameworks - only android. It is almost like their android documentation team is incompetent, for the life of them, they just cant provide a complete, well-written documentation and keep it up to date.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing?_ga=2.200229418.-500468206.1565610311#mobile-static) page you will see the cost of using the [Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) and [Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro)

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLGq4.png)

As you can read it's complete free, but I'm not sure if you must do a billing account to use this API.

Comment: About point 2 i.e 'Draw few markers of locations received from my server.'
Is this also free for the enterprise solution I am going to build?

Comment: Marks like this one: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker should be free too.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Platform APIs usage are tracked for each Product SKU that you are using.
A Google map object in Maps SDK for Android and iOS is using the [Mobile Native Dynamic Maps SKU](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing?_ga=2.200229418.-500468206.1565610311#mobile-dynamic). This SKU is counted per Map Load and each map load is free.

User interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads as well as putting markers in your map.

However, if your app is using the [Dynamic Street View SKU](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing?_ga=2.200229418.-500468206.1565610311#dynamic-street-view) which is counted per Panorama. (This Panorama is created when onCreate() method is called with one of StreetViewPanoramaFragment, SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment, or StreetViewPanoramaView classes in Android or with the GMSPanoramaView object in iOS. This Panorama costs 0.014 USD.

You also need to have a valid billing account enabled in your project to use these SDKs.